# Why variable "q" in quick-sort function equals 7 after first procedure (call)

Tags: c

[image]I have implemented quicksort algorithm in C but I don't know how `q` and `r` work in `quick_sort` function. When the partitioning function returns `i` which is `1` it assigns this value to `q` but then for some reason, `q` becomes `7` and `r` becomes `0`.

```
int partitioning(int A[10], int p, int r);
void quick_sort(int A[10], int p, int r);

int main() {

    int A[10] = { 8, 7, 0, 20, 60, 5, 3, 7, 45, 1}, i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        printf(" %d ", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nFinal Array\n\n");
    quick_sort(A, 0, 9);
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        printf(" %d ", A[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int partitioning(int A[10], int p, int r) {

    int tmp, i, x, j;
    x = A[r];
    i = p - 1;
    for (j = p; j <= r; j++) {
        if (A[j] < x) {
            i++;
            tmp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
    i++;
    tmp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[r];
    A[r] = tmp;

    return i;
}

void quick_sort(int A[10], int p, int r) {
    int q;
    printf("%d\n", q);

    if (p < r) {
        q = partitioning(A, p, r);
        quick_sort(A, p, q - 1);
        quick_sort(A, q + 1, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand recursion. Each call has its own copy of the variables.

Comment: When is `q` becoming `7`? I tried printing `q` each time, it was never `7`.

Comment: When x returns "1" it jumps to quick_sort(A,p,q-1) and then somehow q becomes "7" and r "1"

Comment: How are you seeing that? If you put `printf` statements in the code, please add them to the question and show the output.

Comment: @Barmar I have added printf statment as you told me to do. You will see that q changes from 7 to 60 and etc. It follows the order of unsorted array for some reason.

Comment: @Barmar Also I have added a picture.

Comment: The code you pasted prints the value of `q` before it assigns `q` any value! Whatever value it's going to print is meaningless garbage.